# Twitter oAuth issue: Access token are not being retrieved i

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I am getting following error while trying to fetch access_token:

**The access_token method must be called with a request_token /oauth/access_token?oauth_version=1.0**

Following is my code snippet:

require_once('OAuth_functions.php');

```
$objTwitter = new TwitterOAuth("xxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxx-xxx","xxxxxx");

$access_token = $objTwitter->getAccessToken();
```

While printing the variable $access_token, following response retrieved:

```
Array
(
    [ "1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  The access_token method must be called with a request_token
  /oauth/access_token?oauth_version=1.0
    [amp;oauth_nonce] => xxx
    [amp;oauth_timestamp] => 1311491162
    [amp;oauth_consumer_key] => xxx
    [amp;oauth_token] => xxx-xxx
    [amp;oauth_signature_method] => HMAC-SHA1
    [amp;oauth_signature] => xxx=


)
```

I want to implement SIGN IN WITH TWITTER functionality for my site.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `$_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']` via callback url.
check https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/7771